# Universal quantification via lambda binding?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

I remember once saw somewhere that a universally quantified formula can be written using $\lambda$.  But I cannot recall very clearly.  I have an vague impression that is is something of the form:

$\forall n \in \mathbf{N} . P(n)$ = $? (\lambda n . P(n))$

Please help if you know.  Also, is there any specific reason to write universally quantified formula like this or is it just a style of taste?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

$\forall n \in \mathbf{N} . P(n) = \Pi_\mathbf{N} (\lambda n . P(n))$

It is really nothing special.  Instead of introducing a new binder, it just shift the binding task to an existing binder, namely $\lambda$.  Here $\Pi$ just serves as a marker or a tag, carrying the information that the bound variable $n$ is of type $\mathbf{N}$.  Hence, other symbols will do the job too.